# how do I write a piece of java code that will let an instance happen only once?

Tags: java, blackberry

I am writing an application. In that application I have an instance that I only want to happen the first time that the application is opened. I want to know how to write something in Java that will only make that instance happen that first time. Like a registration code or something like that.

Comment: Can't you maintain a simple boolean flag to keep track of that?

Answer (score 5):

[PersistentStore](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.html) -- create a Singleton. The Blackberry dev forums have an excellent singleton approach that utilizes the RuntimeStore, but that does not cross restarts, PersistentStore does.

Answer (score 4):

"[Item 3](http://drdobbs.com/java/208403883?pgno=3): Enforce the Singleton Property with a Private Constructor or an enum Type"—Joshua Bloch, *Effective Java*.

Comment: PersistentStore -- create a Singleton.
The Blackberry dev forums have an excellent singleton approach that utilizes the RuntimeStore, but that does not cross restarts, PersistentStore does.

Comment: @Dan: Thanks for commenting on this. IIUC, [`PersistentStore`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.html) is particularly apropos to the question. It might be worth making it a separate answer.

Comment: thx trashgod, newb thing -- just spreading the luv an 4getting about status ;)

Answer (score 0):

i know nothing about blackberry, but this seems like it could be answered with a generic answer:

set a flag somewhere