# Using getHostServices() without reference to Application

Tags: javafx

I want to use the following code:

```
File file = new File("/home/marco/eclipse-workspace/Spielwiese/RKI2019_Diabetesbericht.pdf");
HostServices hostServices = getHostServices();
hostServices.showDocument(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

to open a PDF-file in a webbrowser. I need this code in another Java class which does not extend Application. In the following link is a good description how to do it but it does not fit properly because I am not using a fxml-file: [JavaFx 8: open a link in a browser without reference to Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094981/javafx-8-open-a-link-in-a-browser-without-reference-to-application?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I want to have two classes. The main class (which is extending Application) and another one which is not extending Application. In this second class I want to click on a button which than opens the PDF file. Can someone please help me with this issue. I am new to JavaFX and tried really hard but didnt get it to work. Thanks in advance! :)
Following code I produced so far:

Main-Class:

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.HostServices;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            VBox root = new VBox();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            Button button = new Button("Press me");
            root.getChildren().add(button);
            HostServices hostServices = getHostServices();
            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    Test.create(primaryStage, hostServices);
                }
            });
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Other Class:

```
package application;
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.HostServices;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test {
    public static void create (Stage stage, HostServices hostServices){
        GridPane secondarygridpane = new GridPane();
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(secondarygridpane,400,400);
        Button button = new Button ("Press me");
        secondarygridpane.add(button, 0, 0);
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                File file = new File("/home/marco/eclipse-workspace/Spielwiese/RKI2019_Diabetesbericht.pdf");
                HostServices hostServices = getHostServices();
                hostServices.showDocument(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene2);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

If i click on the button a pdf-file should open.

Comment: There's no really pretty way to do this; just pass the `HostServices` reference to the `create` method.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! :)