# How to create singleton objects for external library classes?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is there a better way to create singleton object for external classes? I am doing like below, but is there better way to do this?

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;

public class GetAWSCredentials {
    private static AWSCredentialsProvider credentials;

    public static synchronized AWSCredentialsProvider getInstance() {
        if (credentials == null) {
            credentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
        }
        return credentials;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help: [_how do I write a piece of java code that will let an instance happen only once?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5724888/230513)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Simply this:

```
public class GetAwsCredentials {
    private static final AwsCredentialsProvider credentials = new AwsCredentialsProvider();

    public static AwsCredentialsProvider getInstance() {
        return credentials;
    }
}
```

You might think: Oh no, that won't do! I don't want this instance to be created on JVM bootup, only when needed!

But.. that is already how java works. Classes aren't loaded until needed as is, and 'loading' them doesn't even execute the field initializers - that only happens when the [class is initialized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1), which the JVM does more or less as late as possible. There is virtually no point creating the instance inside some sort of access method; just make it on class initialization. In 99% of all cases where singletons are needed, **if** you are going to mention the relevant class and access some aspect of it that requires that the JVM initializes it, it's probably *because* you called `getInstance()`, or even if not, you are going to end up calling the `getInstance()` method soon after.

In the exceedingly unlikely case you truly do have a need for that (and this *only* counts if that constructor does quite a bit of heavy work, *and* you have `static` methods or other static members *other than* `getInstance()` that you *also* call - **what are the odds**?), you use this construct:

```
public class GetAwsCredentials {
  private static class AwsCredentialsHolder {
    static final AwsCredentialsProvider provider = new AwsCredentialsProvider();
  }

  public static AwsCredentialsProvider getInstance() {
    return AwsCredentialsHolder.provider;
  }
}
```

There is no need to futz with `volatile` or `synchronized`. To wit:

- Those things are either 'too heavy' (such as `synchronized`), or, an attempt to lighten up, e.g. with double checked locking, are 'too light' - they *seem* to work, but under just the right kind of load they'll fail (in the sense that you end up with 2 instances).
- The above uses the fact that java *itself* has a baked in locking mechanism: A class is, guaranteed, never loaded more than once, hence, by having a `static final` field that is initialized right away, we can piggyback on it, and it's the most efficient mechanism for this java offers.
- The second snippet works because that inner class is never even touched until someone calls `.getInstance()`. As long as that inner class isn't touched, it will not be initialized. Even if `new AwsCredentialsProvider()` takes an hour, that hour is not spent until someone calls `.getInstance()`.

NB:

- The right name is `AwsCredentials`, not `AWSCredentials`. In java, naming conventions decree that acronyms are nevertheless written lowercase. It's `DvdPlayer`, not `DVDPlayer`.
- It's probably not correct that you use a singleton here. Test scenarios certainly would want to replace those credentials, for example.

Comment: Both of these techniques can be applied to external classes, and, both snippets indeed do apply it exactly as OP wants. Perhaps you do not understand the problem, @stelios.anastasakis? At best the comment about the proper name of AWSCredentials is meaningless if 'AWSCredentialsProvider' cannot be changed. But GetAwsCredentials is within the control of the asker here.

Comment: Two things: 1) you should replace all occurrences of “loaded” with “initialized” as that’s what it is about. A class may be loaded much earlier, but that doesn’t matter, as the [time of initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) is well defined. 2) Since “to mention the relevant class” is not triggering the initialization of a class (which is distinct from loading a class), there’s even less need for moving the field into a nested class. A case where this would be needed is when having other, unrelated public static members in the outer class.

Comment: @Holger Ah, yes, thanks for the link. Excellent suggestion. I didn't realise it's so unlikely you need to even use the nested class trick. I've edited the answer, both to clarify the difference between load and init, and to further highlight that you don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

Your external library class is not a singleton in this case, cause first of all it is an interface. And even if it wasn't, anyone can create a new instance from outside of this class. You can't turn an external class that is not a singleton in one.

Now, if you want to find the cleanest ways to make a singleton, for your own class GetAWSCredentials, then you can try the [effective-java](https://medium.com/codelog/3-methods-to-create-singleton-with-java-effective-java-learning-notes-12ee8cd27ccd) recommendations